# Selecting radio button and getting corresponding value from it in python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a product page, where there are different variants possible. For each variant that I select (radio button), a different manufacturing number appears. I wish to retrieve this number on selection of different buttons. I wrote the following code, but i get no output or error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.1800cpap.com/resmed-airfit-n30-nasal-cpap-mask-with-headgear")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

size_buttons=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='custcol3' and @type='radio']")
size_buttons
for s in size_buttons:
    s.click()
    mpn= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='mpn-value']")
    print(mpn)
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Change this section -

```
size_buttons=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='custcol3' and @type='radio']")
size_buttons
for s in size_buttons:
    s.click()
    mpn= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='mpn-value']")
    print(mpn)
```

to

```
size_buttons=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.custcol3-controls.product-views-option-tile-container > label")
size_buttons
for s in size_buttons:
    s.click()
    
    mpn= driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.addmanufacturermpn-info-card-content > span:nth-child(2)")
    print(mpn)
```

Comment: this does not seem to work. it gives the error 'element not interactable'

Comment: could you also probably check this out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653546/looping-over-all-radio-buttons-in-a-page-using-selenium-in-python/62654609#62654609

Comment: this works fine for a single button, how do i extend it for all buttons on a page